# Android programming using eclipse,

Tags: android

I need to know how to develop database driven application, i have three tables. how to put data in database and how to report them?

Comment: what does this have to do with Android or Eclipse exactly?

Comment: SQLite and [android](http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html) [programming](http://commonsware.com/Android/)

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Absolutely true @Thor I am a bit ashamed that I didn't know better at the time. Im gonna come back to this and expand it into a better answer. Thank you for bringing it to my attention.